# recreate my master branch  in git

Tags: git

My master branch is now not up to date and when I pull from the release branch I get too many conflicts 
how can I track the release branch and replacing the old code with the new one, I've tried the following :

```
git branch --track master ...
```

this doesn't work because the master branch is already created.

```
git breanch --set-upstream master ...
```

didn't work also,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed my problem just by adding the ***-f*** to the track command

```
git br --track master CC/dev -f
```